# Gulp Browsersync pathing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gulp

I got a problem with requesting a file via ajax post request.

I wonder how do I map my file on an ajax call to match the servers pathing? I don't get why it is not working (was using XAMPP before switching to a gulp webserver). Here is my project structure:

```html
./
|_ site/
|  |_ index.html
|  |_ php/Gallery.php
|  |_ assets/
|     |_ js/
|        |_ Ajax.js
|        |_ test.html
|
|_ dist/
|
|_ gulpfile.js
|_ package.json
|_ ...
```

The Ajax.js file does an Post request to get php/gallery.php however I get a 404. I tried "php/Gallery.php" and "../../php/Gallery.php" as a path (and lots of others but try and error did not get me any further)

The Ajax call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "php/Gallery.php",
    type: 'post',
    data: { width: $(window).width(), galleryWidth: $('.popup-gallery').innerWidth(),},
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $( ".ajax-loading" ).css('display', 'block');
    },
    success: function(json) {
       ... do something
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log("Ajax Error: "+ err);
    }
  }); // end ajax call
```

I tried to access the test.html file inside of my /js folder with the path: "assets/js/test.html" and I get a 404 there too. If I type the URL "http://localhost:3000/assets/js/test.html" the test.html file gets displayed fine with its "Hello world" so I get really confused.

See picture:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/n71op0.jpg
(external link cause you need 10 reputation to post images, sadly)

If someone could explain what I am doing wrong here or where's my mistake I would be really grateful!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the gulp webserver can not interpret PHP. Now I use Xampp and let browsersync proxy through it.